# Convergence / Divergence of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Discuss the convergence or divergence of the following sequence. Also find the limit if it
converges-
$a_{1}=2$ , $a _{n+1}=72/(1+a_{n})$
I noticed that we can break it up into two sequences , with one increasing and one decreasing , not sure how to proceed.
I think we can show one sequence is bounded and monotonic , and hence convergent. How shall I show that the resulting sequence is also convergent / divergent ? .

Comment: the limit $a=8$ satisfies $a=72/(1+a)$

Comment: Can you please explain how you did this ? I must first show that it is convergent / divergent and then find the limit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have proved that the subsequences $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ are bounded and monotonic, therefore they converge. Here is the way you can go on :

Let $$f : x \mapsto \frac{72}{1+x}$$

You have $a_{2(n+1)} = f(a_{2n+1}) = f \circ f (a_{2n})$, and $a_{2(n+1)+1} = f(a_{2n+2}) = f \circ f (a_{2n+1})$, so both limits of $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ are fixed points of $f \circ f$.

But
$$f \circ f(l)=l \Longleftrightarrow \frac{72}{1+\frac{72}{1+l}}=l \Longleftrightarrow 72(1+l)=l(1+l+72)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow l^2 +l - 72 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (l-8)(l+9)=0$$

But the value $l=-9$ is impossible because (you should have proved that) the sequence is positive. Therefore, both $(a_{2n})$ and $(a_{2n+1})$ converge to $8$, and therefore, $(a_n)$ converges to $8$.